# Show a confirm message before <p:rowEditor> updates the model on click of "OK" button

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, confirm, roweditor

I'm using `<p:rowEditor>` as follows:

```
<p:column headerText="Libellé">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{lot.libelle}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText value="#{lot.libelle}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>

<p:column>
    <p:rowEditor />
</p:column>
```

I would like to show a confirm message before the `<p:rowEditor>` updates the model on click of the "OK" button. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please, "alert message" is not the same as "confirm message". I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onstart` attribute of `<p:ajax event="rowEdit">` for this.

```
<p:dataTable ...>
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" onstart="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks! But can I add `Yes` or `No` buttons ?