# show confirmDialog before rowEditor updates the model

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, roweditor

I'm using PrimeFaces dataTable and rowEditor in pretty default way:

```
<p:dataTable id="payments-table" var="apayment" value="#{payment.payments}" editable="true">
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{payment.update}"/>

    ...

</p:dataTable>
```

I'd like a confirmation dialog to show itself on clicking to the 'check' button of rowEditor.

I know it's possible using JS confirm function (thanks to [Show a confirm message before <p:rowEditor> updates the model on click of "OK" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076651/show-a-confirm-message-before-proweditor-updates-the-model-on-click-of-ok-b)):

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{payment.update}" onstart="return confirm('Save changes?')"/>
```

But I would like the dialog to conform to the UI theme, confirmDialog component being the best candidate. Alas, I don't know how to use it here. I tried the following and it won't work (simply no confirmation occurres):

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{payment.update}">
    <p:confirm header="Remove payment" message="Remove payment?" icon="ui-icon-trash"/>
</p:ajax>
....
<p:confirmDialog global="true">
    <h:form id="form-payment-confirm">
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
    </h:form>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use in this case simple widgetVar and call show() or hide() functions. Here is your modified code:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onRowEdit}" oncomplete="myDialog.show()"/>
```

I use PF 3.5 and can't find global parameter in p:confirmDialog. May be it is new feature. So I simple deleted it of my code. Here is modified confirmDialog:

```
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="myDialog" closeOnEscape="true" appendToBody="true" closable="true">
                <h:form id="form-payment-confirm">
                    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" update="@form" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" onclick="myDialog.hide()" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                </h:form>
            </p:confirmDialog>
```

Please try and adjust this confirm dialog code! May be unnecessary code for update form or hide()...

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to dynamically adjust text message of confirmDialog, you can adjust from server-side. Perhaps it is not best solution. I think the second way is it adjust from client-side by JQuery.

### Server-side:

The ajax event is same. It call onRowEdit listener which adjust simple String attribute. For example the bean containt:

```
String myDialogMessage = "Default message";
//getter and setter

 public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        myDialogMessage="Are you sure?";
    }
```

and the dialog containt message property:

```
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="myDialog" closeOnEscape="true" appendToBody="true" closable="true" message="{tableBean.myDialogMessage}">
```

### Client-side:

You can use repleaceWith function of JQuery:

```
<script>
  jQuery("myDialog.p").replaceWith(....
</script>
```

Of course need to develop more business logic to client-side, more functions. Maybe the server-side solution is faster.

Please try it!

---

Based on your comment, I **edited**:

I find this in [4.0 user' guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html):

> When pencil icon is clicked, row is displayed in editable mode meaning
>   input facets are displayed  and output facets are hidden. Clicking
>   tick icon only saves that particular row and cancel icon  reverts the
>   changes, both options are implemented with ajax interaction. Another
>   option for incell editing is cell editing, in this mode a cell
>   switches to edit mode when it is  clicked, losing focus triggers an
>   ajax event to save the change value.

So ajax event works when row is change. Here is dataTable events which can you catch:

[image]

I hope this answer help to you find solution!

Comment: I think you meant `onstart` instead of `oncomplete` (result is same). It doesn't work -- dialog is shown with no text and icon (because it is run not via p:confirm) and in the background behind the dialog it can be seen that editing has been finished already. So, this dialog doesn't block the rowEdit event.

Comment: So you want to adjust dynamically text of confirmDialog. I will update my answer. Please check it!

Comment: The most critical problem is that row editing isn't blocked by the dialog -- on the part of the screen not obscurred by it I can see that editing has been finished (controls V and X disappeared, and pencil appeared back).

Comment: Yes are you right. I think you are want to merge p:dataTable with p:confirmDialog. I will edit my answer.